# How to change app store user for pre-installed apps on a Mac?

Tags: mac, applications, mac-appstore

We have two Macs in the family, one registered to me, the other to the wife. Whenever I tend to updating both machines, I have to call in the wife, to let her enter her AppStore password for the iLife apps (Numbers, Pages, etc). However, I have those apps as well, but the Mac AppStore does not let me use my account for this machine. Is there an easy way to change this, so that I can update the apps with my account?

Comment: Can you use [family sharing](http://www.apple.com/icloud/family-sharing/)?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an automated way to do that.

You would need to request a new redemption code from Apple for all of the apps. I've seen them grant that for businesses that can prove they purchased the Macs.

For used Macs, I've generally bought a gift card for the buyer or discounted the selling price to account for the lack of license for the built in apps.

I suppose you could ask for a "do-over" for that Mac to Apple Support if you can't put both accounts in a Family Sharing situation and use the AppleID you want to access "puchases" from another account.

Comment: That sounds complicated. Can't I just, e.g. delete the apps, and reinstall them via my AppStore account?

Comment: You'd have to buy them again if you did that. Really, it seems that all you need is to set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060)

Comment: I just tried my solution: I deleted the three apps and opened my AppStore, and clicked "Install" for all three apps. They are downloading now (remember: I have another Mac with those apps, on my account). But I will look into Family Sharing as well!